# WordPress Number of Posts Not Changing With posts_per_page

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, query, pre-get-posts

I have thousands of posts that I am displaying on my home page. I want to control number of posts so for this I am using `posts_per_page`but it is not working for me. All other arguments works but `posts_per_page` is not working. I have pagination on this page and `posts_per_page` works for all other pages of pagination but not for first (main) page.
So for testing purpose i create a blank template that just have one simple WordPress loop and not have pagination or any thing else that is displaying just post title and in this template i have limit on number of posts again but `posts_per_page` is not working even on this page.
I have tried disabling all plugins but there was no effect so i think this issue is with theme that is setting `posts_per_page` value dynamically.
I am also resetting the query before this loop using `wp_reset_query();` and tried this code in `functions.php` as well.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts',  'set_posts_per_page'  );
function set_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    global $wp_the_query;
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 12 );
    return $query;
}
```

But nothing working for me. I have tried to display query content using `var_dump($query->request)`and in the query limit was 12 but on page i am still seeing 100+ posts. On WordPress settings page on theme settings page the posts limit is 12 but on front end this limit is not working. Here is the result of this query.

```
string(489) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_mdw75t47kk_posts.ID FROM wp_mdw75t47kk_posts INNER JOIN wp_mdw75t47kk_postmeta ON ( wp_mdw75t47kk_posts.ID = wp_mdw75t47kk_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_mdw75t47kk_postmeta.meta_key = '_imwb_zonpress_post_ctr' ) AND wp_mdw75t47kk_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_mdw75t47kk_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_mdw75t47kk_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_mdw75t47kk_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_mdw75t47kk_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC LIMIT 0, 12"
```

I am also sharing url of this testing page if anybody wants to see this.
[Test Page link](http://ifyougiveagirlaleotard.com/test/)
You will also be able to see this issue on main page as well. For me this is very strange issue because i have tried everything from google but nothing working for me. 
I am using covert store builder theme. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Here is complete code for this loop.

```
wp_reset_query(); 
$args = Array(
        'posts_per_page' => 12
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

Then there is some code to display image, title and excerpt and I think this should not effect number of posts. After this these lines are given

```
<?php 
endwhile; ?>
```

But as i mention i have tried this code in a blank template without pagination but still posts_per_page was not working. So i think an external hook setting this value. I have tried to find out this in theme files but was not successful. I know this is just because of this theme.

Comment: How are the posts loaded on the homepage?

Comment: Jobs are loading with simple WordPress loop which is working perfectly and everything else in loop arguments as well but posts_per_page is not working.

Comment: Would you please add the code that handles pagination?

Comment: Yes I can add that. But i have tried this even without pagination in a custom template but still number of posts was 100 plus.

Comment: Have you tried switching to a default theme and disabling all plugins? It sounds like there may be another hook affecting this secondary query.

Comment: I think your problem is related to the paged param, try the query using a default value like `min(1, get_query_var( 'page' ))`

Comment: I have tried disabling all plugins but the issue was still there. I know this is just because of this theme and an external hook setting this value because i have tried this in a blank template without pagination code and the issue was still there.

Comment: @Awan Could you paste some more info about this problem? How does the loop on home page look like? Are there any other actions attached to `pre_get_posts` hook? What is the value of posts per page option on settings page?

Comment: Posts_per_page value is 10 on settings page and on theme settings page. I have tried everything on this and have spent a lot of time but could not understand why it is not working. I know it is very minor issue but could not understand why it is not working.

Comment: try this `var_dump($query->request)` to see what is inside your query, it's a starting point to debug the problem

Comment: As i mention i have tried a very simple loop in a blank page without pagination and any other thing but still posts_per_page not working. All other arguments works but this one not working. So i think external hook setting its value.

Comment: @AlexSancho here is the result and the limit is 10 but number of posts still 100+. string(489) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_mdw75t47kk_posts.ID FROM wp_mdw75t47kk_posts INNER JOIN wp_mdw75t47kk_postmeta ON ( wp_mdw75t47kk_posts.ID = wp_mdw75t47kk_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_mdw75t47kk_postmeta.meta_key = '_imwb_zonpress_post_ctr' ) AND wp_mdw75t47kk_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_mdw75t47kk_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_mdw75t47kk_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_mdw75t47kk_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_mdw75t47kk_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC LIMIT 0, 10"

Comment: If you want to see, i can share url of this test page that is assigned with a blank template.

Comment: have you tried `suppress_filters` in your query or removing all filters from pre_get_posts?

Comment: Yes i tried this.

Comment: Could you give us the link?

Comment: @Awan if the sql has a limit of 10 than it is something else on that page that does the excessive display. Maybe you repeat the loop until it prints all the posts.

Comment: @MarkKaplun thank you for your time and help. But here on this testing page i have very simple loop that just printing title on each separate line. I do not have pagination or any thing else on this testing template.

Comment: For me this is very strange issue because i have tried everything for this issue from google but nothing working for me

Comment: @Awan Please [edit] your question, and move all crucial information from the comments to the question text, so we can clean up this overly long comment thread. :)

Comment: @fuxia I will add this info to my question now.

Comment: What do you have under Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most?

Comment: Where did you put this `var_dump`? Is it on some action/filter or in template code of your theme?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż It is in template file.

Comment: Under settings this limit is 12 again.

Comment: OK, so if the SQL query is limited to 12, then there is no way that it gets more than 12 posts. Your posts have to be displayed some other way, or there is some code that modifies your WP_Query object, or something like that...

Comment: Yes i think an external hook setting this value but i have check this in theme files and place my own hook that i mention in my question as well. But nothing working for me. This is minor issue but taking days. I do not know where i am wrong

Comment: Confirm you are modifying the correct template with: `echo basename( get_page_template() )`. Eliminate the possibility of posts loading from a transient by clearing them, example SQL query: `DELETE FROM 'wp_mdw75t47kk_options' WHERE 'option_name' LIKE ('_transient_%');`. - Be very careful here. Be sure to eliminate any server side caching and clear those. The example link you sent uses a child theme from covertstorebuilder. Could the main query be altered in the parent? Finally output the full $wp_query object on your test link if there are no security concerns. That can be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this one?

```
<?php 
    $blogpost  =  new WP_Query(array(         
       'post_type'      => 'post',
       'posts_per_page' => 6
        ));
?>
<?php while($blogpost->have_posts()) : $blogpost->the_post(); ?>
// Writhe your Blog article Here.
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: That is useful for me to change default posts_per_page in search.php while loop to display more excerpts in search results layout.  But pagination is broken. TwentySeventeen (child) theme

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this one?

```
function posts_on_homepage( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'posts_on_homepage' );
```

Comment: Tried this but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this one before the query argument.

```
    if (get_query_var('paged')) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } elseif (get_query_var('page')) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
    } else {
        $paged = 1;
    }
```

At the argument, make `'paged' => $paged`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following before the main args and the loop?

```
<!-- Modify pagination function for front page -->
<?php
global $paged, $wp_query, $wp;
$args = wp_parse_args($wp->matched_query);
if ( !empty ( $args['paged'] ) && 0 == $paged ) {
$wp_query->set('paged', $args['paged']);
$paged = $args['paged']; } ?>
```

Then add the pagination like so:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 12,
'paged' => $paged ); ?>

$query = new WP_Query($args);

<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : $i = 1; ?>

<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

// Content Here

<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<h2>Content not found!</h2>
<?php endif; ?>

//pagination code
```

In my case I am using WP pagenavi, so I would use:

```
<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query )); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your theme is binding to a filter that is resetting the query also within your loop, which is causing unending recursion. If that is the case, you have three options:

You can ditch the theme and use another one. That is probably a bad answer if you are heavily invested in it.

You can hack the theme, which is also a bad answer, because you'll have to do it again when it updates, or you'll have to override a bunch of its core code in a child theme which can get very messy.

Or, you can do it the quick and dirty way, which is to just use a good old `for` loop instead of `while`.

```
wp_reset_query();
$GLOBALS['my_counter'] = 12;
$args = Array(
    'posts_per_page' => $GLOBALS['my_counter'];
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

<?php
for ( $i = 0; $i < $GLOBALS['my_counter'], $i++ )
{
    if (!$query->the_post())
    {
        break;
    }
}
unset($GLOBALS['my_counter']);
?>
```

It's ugly, but it should do what you want. The `for` loop will only run 12 times, regardless of whether or not anything else is resetting the query. If you see duplicate posts, you can also put a break point in the loop and use `debug_backtrace(1)` to sniff out where it is happening, which is not really feasible in a `while` loop, unless you like the idea of about 8 bjillionty pages of debug code and possibly crashing your server.

---

If this does work for you, consider finding a more elegant solution for a couple of reasons:

**A)** Globals are bad.

**B)** Doing things the wrong way usually leads to more doing things the wrong way. I can't say what is the right way for your specific theme, but if it provides any way to do what you want on your home page, you should do that. If it does not provide any kind of api though, do what you have to.