# Change the number of excerpts displayed in search results layout

Tags: posts, pagination, excerpt

WP 5.1 TwentySeventeen (child) theme.

```
_posts_per_page = 1
```

For search results I want to display 5 excerpts.
Using this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/298118/66849) and this [page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) I was able to do that but displayed excerpts are not from search results, they are the last 5 published posts.

This is how the loop looks in modified search.php:

```
    <?php 
    $blogpost = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 5));
    if ( $blogpost->have_posts() ) :
    //if ( have_posts() ) :
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( $blogpost->have_posts() ) :
        //while ( have_posts() ) :
            $blogpost->the_post();
            //the_post();

            /**
             * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
             * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
             * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'excerpt' );

        endwhile; // End of the loop.    
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

And the pagination code:

```
        the_posts_pagination(
            array(
                'prev_text'          => twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-left' ) ) . '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>',
                'next_text'          => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-right' ) ),
                'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . ' </span>',
            )
        );
```

Number of excerpts displayed are okay but they are not taken from Search Results (despite the keyword entered, the output is always the same, the last 5 published posts).

Note: With modified search.php pagination corresponds to the real search results. Because default posts per page = 1 if real search result finds 3 posts so 1·2·3 is displayed at bottom.

How can I output a desired number of excerpts from search results and get pagination according to that?

Comment: You are missing the `s` parameter in the WP_Query call. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter

Comment: I see, thanks. So `$blogpost = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 's' => get_search_query()));` How to fix pagination? I still see `1·2·3` despite the 3 results are in the first page.  If I have more than 5 results second page output is the same as the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search on wp it automatically does a search query. In your code you make a new WP_Query to show 5 posts (which sorts by data by default) and there is no need to do that.

The best thing to do here is to leave the `search.php` file as it is and use an action hook. You can add this to your child theme functions.php file.

```
function my_search_filter( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
      $query->set('posts_per_page', '5');
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','my_search_filter');
```